# Задача с вложенными циклами

Tags: javascript

Нужно нарисовать строку с помощью вложенного цикла:

```
 10x01x
 10x01x
 10x01x
```

У меня получилось так:

```
 10x010
 10x010
 10x010
```

Сделал все через оператор `%` узнав остаток, а для `'x'` написал отдельную инструкцию через `else if`. Но проблема в том, что `if` записывает 0 первее, чем `else if` для второго `'x'`.

```
let out6 = document.querySelector('#out6');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            out6.innerHTML += 0;
        }
        else if (j == 3 || j == 6) {
            out6.innerHTML += 'x';
        }
        else {
            out6.innerHTML += 1;
        }
    }
    out6.innerHTML += '<br>';
}
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: а нельзя вложенный цикл сделат ьвида `let chart = "10x01x".split(); for().... -> chars[i]` ? есть какие-то дополнитльные требования к извращениями этим с %2, 3 || 6 ?

Comment: Извращения должны быть, на то это и задача.

Comment: ну поменяй местами, делов-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поменяйте инструкции местами.

```
let out6 = document.querySelector('#out6');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
        if (j == 3 || j == 6) {
            out6.innerHTML += 'x';
        }
        else if (j % 2 == 0) {
            out6.innerHTML += 0;
        }
        else {
            out6.innerHTML += 1;
        }
    }
    out6.innerHTML += '<br>';
}
```

Еще можно заменить `j==3 || j==6` на `j % 3 == 0`.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если там нет ограничения на количество вложенных циклов, то можно так

```js
let str = '';

for (let a = 0; a < 3; a++) { //цикл-обертка для вывода строки три раза
  for (let i = 1; i > 0; i--) {
    str += `${i}`;
    for (let j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
      str += `${j}x`;
      if (j === 1) continue;

      for (let k = 0; k <= 0; k++) {
        str += `${k}`;
      }
    }
  }
  str += `<br>`;
}

document.write(str);
console.log(str);
```